# Android Programming, Static variables

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static-variables

I am new to Android programming and I have a question. I have an activity class and a java class. The java class is used to create a database. When pressing a button in the activity class the database gets populated with some data. After I populate the database I want to go back to the activity and be able to display the data in the database. I have a variable `profileStatus` which has the `false` value and I want to change its value to `true` after I populate the database. `profileStatus` is a static variable so I accessed it from the java class `MainActivity.profileStatus=true` but after I returned to the activity, the value is still false. Here are my codes.

This is in the MainActivity class.

```
public void profileStatus(View view){
    if(profileStatus==false){
        createProfile(view);`
    }
    else if(profileStatus==true){
        displayProfile(view)}
```

This is what I have in the java class.

```
if(counter==5){
        profileValues.put(col_1,a);
        profileValues.put(col_2,b);
        profileValues.put(col_3,c);
        profileValues.put(col_4,d);
        profileValues.put(col_5,e);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,profileValues);
        MainActivity.profileStatus=true;

    }
```

I am accessing the variable `profileStatus`, but when I return to the activity, the value is still false. Any help?

Comment: where did you define the profileStatus and when did you change it's value? plz show all of them.

Comment: The profileStatus is declared as a static field of MainActivity and is initialised with "false" value to allow the profile to be created. Then from the java class I am attempting to change its value to true so that when I will return to the MainActivity I will be able to display the profile not to create it again.

Comment: How many activities are there? Could you post the complete Activity code in which you have declared the static variable `profileStatus` and the database helper class.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Log.i in both places. Then by looking at the log you can tell which one runs first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use some static object, it will be better use it with Singleton pattern. 
Activity life cycle don't persist your variable as you suppose(as i think it's your case), because you get instance of this variable not from Activity instance, but from static field of non instatiated class. There are a couple of solutions.
 1. Send reference of your field in constructor(in this case profileStatus better to be non static).

```
public class YourJavaClass {
   var profileStatus;
   public YourJavaClass(var profileStatus) {
    this.profileStatus = profileStatus;
}
}
```

2. Send Activity reference. Code looks like the same but your variable field you get from Activity (MainActivity.profileStatus)
3. Use Singleton class for example Application extending. Define static instance of this class and place your field which you use as static to this class

   public class MyAndroidApplication extends Application {
    private var profileStatus; 
    private static MyAndroidApplication sAppInstance;

   ```
     {
       sAppInstance = this;
     }

     public static MyAndroidApplication getAppInstance() {
       return sAppInstance;
   ```

   }

   ```
     public var getProfileStatus() {
       return profileStatus;
   ```

   } 
   }

   And in your java class, to get your variable use this

MyAndroidApplication.getAppInstance.getProfileStatus and you can change this variable as you wish

***"var" means your type, for example boolean profileStatus**

Answer (score 0):

This profileStatus

```
  MainActivity.profileStatus=true;
```

is not this profileStatus

```
public void ...(View view){ 
    if(profileStatus==false)
```

regardless of any modifiers, eg: static.

If you'e serious about accessing your db you'll need to use the activity instance's profileStatus.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to load the database the first time you open the MainActivity and display the data on subsequent opening.

Instead of static variable, use SharedPreference to store the profile status

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("profileStatus", true);
editor.commit();
```

And to get the value of profileStatus

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
profileStatus = sharedPref.getBoolean("profileStatus", false);
```